# trouble when running composer

Tags: php, json, symfony, composer-php

On my **Symfony** project, I have some error when running `composer update/install` command:

This is the error occured when I run composer:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 524288 bytes) in
>   phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php
>   on line 189

[image]

As you can see I run the prompt command as administrator, but even if I run the command as not admin, the same error occured.

I also check the page [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors) in order to set the change they recommand me to run composer without troubles.

I am on Windows 10 and using wamp server for my project.
So in my php.ini i wrote this line: `memory_limit = 2G`

I restart wamp and so my computer in order to be sure. And when I run the command `php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"` it always show `128M`.

If I run `composer diagnose` command this is what I get from the prompt command :
[image]

As you can see here, composer show me an error on my composer.json.
This my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
        "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "~1.1",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^1.5",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1",
        "sonata-project/seo-bundle": "^2.0",
        "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "elao/web-profiler-extra-bundle" : "~2.3@dev",
        "maxmind/geoip": "dev-master",
        "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "^2.0",
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "^1.0",
        "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "^1.0",
        "sp/bower-bundle": "^0.11.0",
        "ensepar/html2pdf-bundle" : "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "BetonDirect\\EntityBundle\\HerokuDatabase::populateEnvironment"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "hard-copy",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
            "env-map": {
                "database_driver": "DATABASE_DRIVER",
                "database_host": "DATABASE_HOST",
                "database_port": "DATABASE_PORT",
                "database_name": "DATABASE_NAME",
                "database_user": "DATABASE_USER",
                "database_password": "DATABASE_PASSWORD"
            }
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

I also disable in my wamp ,server xdebug zend extension, but it does not work too (same problem when I change the memory_limit, nothing change).

If you have some issues, I appreciate.

Comment: Do you really need the `minimum-stabilitiy` option set to `dev`? Doing so requires Composer's dependency resolver to take much more versions into account which drastically increases the memory usage.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the php.ini for PHP CLI? There are usually two separate configs, one for the web server and one for CLI.

Comment: @JimL I already change the `memory_limit` to 2G in the two php.ini in wamp, e-g in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12` and in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin`. You think there are not the right files ?

Comment: Maybe, run `php --ini`to make sure

Comment: @french_dev Can you please answer my question about the `minimum-stability` option? Increasing the memory limit might let the error message disappear, but will not solve the issue of too many versions/commits taken into account during dependency resolution.

Comment: @xabbuh to answer (and sorry for the late), it's a versionning project, and I start to work on it, so I recover the composer.json in this state. You suggest me to remove the line `"minimum-stability": "dev"` ? I think if the `minimum-stabilitiy` is in dev because of some packages like `FOSUserBundle` are parameters in the current symfony project I work on, and there is a possibility that update him will cause some troubles too. What do you suggest me ?

Comment: @JimL ok thanks to you I solve the problem. I didnot understand really why but I have another php.ini activated on my windows computer for a vagrant (VM), I just delete the VM and my memory limit reach the 2G. Thank to the command `php --ini`. It is a bad way to set the memory_limit to 2G like I have done ?

Comment: If there are only some packages for which you want to (or have to) use their dev versions, you can still suffix the version number of those packages with `@dev` (or any other stability flag). This will force Composer to only take dev versions of those packages into account while using stable versions for every other package.

Comment: @xabbuh I will follow your suggestion. Thank you by the way. It's a pleasure to have some advice for better dev. And sorry if the question seems not so appropriate for a developper.

Comment: @JimL ruuning the composer install or update command works well now. Just create the answer, you help me a lot in order I post the question as resolved. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are editing the wrong php ini

To find out which php.ini you have to edit for cli

in cmd type  `php -i`

and search for `php.ini`

or place `echo phpinfo()`

in RemoteFilesystem.php on line 180 or whatever and search stdout for php.ini

Comment: Not only this does not answer the question. But it's already been suggested in comments (as it should).

Comment: i think the correct answer is, "you edited the wrong php config" here is an idea how you can find out the right one

Comment: Well, we can argue over the semantics of what should be a comment and what should be an answer. I am no Meta expert. Two things are obvious though: 1. You didn't write your answer like that. Not even after you edited your answer. 2. Your "solution" has already been suggested and replied to by OP prior to your posting of the answer. I feel that's enough to vote down an answer. I am sorry if you disagree. I do not mean to be mean. I only strive for a better SO where the OP gets a proper reply but also the next people who search for the answer may find useful information, presented properly.

Comment: @SimpleAnecdote - So think about the future person searching for the answer.  They can read this (hopefully soon to be accepted) answer and quickly determine the problem.  Or they can wade through 10 (mostly irrelevant) comments and maybe pick out what needs to be done.  Which would you rather do?  Granted he should updated his answer to php --ini but what he has works.

Comment: Except that he didn't answer in the comments, and when he posted his answer the method seemed to be not working. It's only afterwards that the OP found out that indeed this is the command to check. Also, at least now there's context. So now it's fine(ish) because he's not the guy who solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you have the 32bit PHP version installed for Windows, the memory limit is 2GB here. You can install 64bit PHP version and have a memory limit of 4GB which should be enough.

Here is a tutorial:

http://sebastianviereck.de/en/Windows-composer-update-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-1610612736-bytes-exhausted/

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution in windows 10

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar update
```